# Remote MySQL connection timing out

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP application that runs on my server along with its MySQL database, the database contains security keys.

Site A connects to the applications MySQL database remotely to fetch the security key and works with no issues.
Site B however returns a MySQL connection timed out error.

So basically one of the external servers connects to the database with no issues, but the other times out. It's the exact same script on both servers and both of the external servers are listed in the cPanel. Both servers have the same mysql connect timeout value set in php.ini of 60 seconds, Site B returns the time out error after around 5 seconds.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you granted site B access to the database as per https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mysql/remote-access/

Comment: Well since I didn't do that for Site A and it works fine, why would Site B require it?

Answer (score 2):

By default, cPanel don't allow remote connection to db for protections,
you should add both remote server IP's in the allowed remote connection list, in the db website cPanel, or allow connections for all IP's (add `%` only)

Another thing might block the connection if you have a CSF (ConfigServer Security & Firewall) on Server B, then you need to confirm that mysql port `3306` is allowed (you need root level for that, or ask the server admin).

Comment: Yeah, I'm already using the wildcard % in cPanel. The thing is it doesn't display an error like can't connect or wrong information, just connection timed out which is the same error if I would change the server address to some random made up URL or DNS, it's almost like the server can't connect to anything.

Comment: Firewall blocking port connection will also give connection time out,
you need to allow that port or ask the server admin to do so.
you can confirm by try to connect to server B db remotely , it also should give you timeout

Answer (score 2):

Blocking port causes a time out. You can reproduce it via the following command, excecuted from the server which want to connect:

```
telnet hostname_or_ip 3306
```

See the response data. No response? Blocked.

Secondly: be sure that the ip of the server is whitelisted by the mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Telnet access on server B then telnet to MySQL and see if you can get a response.

Also check that site B is configured to use the same MySQL port as site A. You might want to explicitly specify it in the script, so the configured default is overridden.

Lion4H has also raised some very good information. Very likely to be a firewall issue.