# Laravel 8 - How to solve Connection timed out while using remote MYSQL database?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

In one of my Laravel 8 applications, I need to use two databases where one is a remote database. In my local development environment, the remote database is working fine (I can fetch data), but the problem arises only when I host the application in production. Every time it responds connection time out even for a simple query like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'my_target_email_address'`

Here is my .env file code:

```
# Local DB
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=bint_gt
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

# REMOTE DB
REMOTE_DB_CONNECTION=mysql
REMOTE_DB_HOST=REMOTE_DB_HOST
REMOTE_DB_PORT=3306
REMOTE_DB_DATABASE=REMOTE_DB
REMOTE_DB_USERNAME=REMOTE_DB_USER
REMOTE_DB_PASSWORD=REMOTE_DB_PASSWORD
```

Here is the updated code for the remote database in the **config/database.php** file:

```
'remote_mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('MFO_DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('MFO_DB_HOST'),
    'port' => env('MFO_DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('MFO_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('MFO_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('MFO_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('MFO_DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

Finally, run the following MySQL query to fetch data:

```
$userEmail = Auth::user()->email;
$userInfo = DB::connection('remote_mysql')->select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='$userEmail'");
if( !empty($userInfo) ) {
    $uid = $userInfo[0]->uid;
    # do rest of the work
} else {
    # return JSON response of user not found
}
```

Everything works fine in my local development environment (XAMPP), although the speed is a little bit slow, it does not work on the production server.

N.B: I am using Plesk rather cPanel.

Can anyone help me to figure out how to fix the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remote MySQL connection timing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188496/remote-mysql-connection-timing-out)